# PostgreSQL - Function declaration - Dynamic WHERE in QUERY

Tags: postgresql

How to change "EXECUTE sql_string" to "RETURN QUERY" in a function declaration, but there is a where array which must be used.
In other words, how to change this

```
p_sql := 'SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE ' || array_to_string(where_arr, ' AND ');

FOR item IN EXECUTE p_sql
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT item;
  END LOOP;
```

to this

```
RETURN QUERY
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE || array_to_string(where_arr, ' AND '); -- this is the place
```

I want my editors (phpstorm, notepad++) to see SQL as SQL and not as string.

Comment: What is the content of that `where_arr`?

Comment: where_arr has strings

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING

```
return query execute $$
    select *
    from tbl
    where $$ || array_to_string(where_arr, ' and ');
```

Comment: Good answer. But this is almost the same.

Comment: @wevu It is the answer to the question you made as I understand it. You are just missing the `execute` and that is only what is missing. No other answer is possible other than pointing to the fact that you are taking the wrong approach to the problem.

Comment: Yes, my fault. My editors (phpstorm, notepad++) interpreters these as strings, and I want them as SQL code.